# jQuery - Ajax POST request converted to GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to POST json data via ajax. The json data contains a large html table. However, this POST request is converted to GET request and I get Error 414 (Request-URI too long). I know jsonp POST requests are converted to GET, but why my json request is converted to GET?

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'call': 'emailSalesReportToAdmin',
            'tableHtml': $('#tblSalesReport').parent().html()
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , for older version, please use ***type:'POST'*** instead of ***method:'POST'***

As mentioned on [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> type (default: 'GET') Type: String An alias for method. You should use
>   type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was an older version of jQuery. The above code worked fine in jQuery version 1.12.